# Open local folder using tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I am well aware that local file access is severely restricted if not outright impossible in modern browsers.

However, what I wonder, is if it would be possible to actually use tampermonkey with "allow access to file urls" extension option enabled to bypass this restriction? If so, how can I attempt it? I tried using local filepaths in several variants (`\\\\`, `file://`) but it doesn't seem to work, and I couldn't find any relevant information in the web either.

//edit//
I want to open local folder in system file explorer.

Comment: You are correct, it sounded vague - I added a comment. I mean file explorer.

Comment: Userscripts can't do it. Even extensions can't do it directly - only via an additional utility that's installed separately and which can be controlled by an extension using nativeMessaging API.